# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in Nextjs when deploying to Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, typeerror

I have got the below file which complains of TypeError.

I am trying to deploy the application in Vercel using Nextjs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Please find the code below

```
import { RawNodeDatum } from 'react-d3-tree/lib/types/common';

interface nodeBFSInterface {
  name: string;
  tree: RawNodeDatum | RawNodeDatum[];
  newNodeName: string;
  attributes: {
    type: string;
    url?: string | undefined;
    weight?: number | undefined;
  };
}

function nodeBFS(nodeBFSInterface: nodeBFSInterface) {
  const queue: RawNodeDatum[] = [];
  queue.unshift(nodeBFSInterface.tree as RawNodeDatum);

  //console.log("before while loop", queue);
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const curNode = queue.pop();
    //console.log("inside while loop", curNode);
    if (
      curNode!.name === nodeBFSInterface.name &&
      nodeBFSInterface.attributes?.type === 'landerRotator'
    ) {
      try {
        curNode!.children!.push({
          name: (nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName)?nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName: '',
          attributes: { type: nodeBFSInterface.attributes.type },
          children: [],
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      return { ...nodeBFSInterface.tree };
    } else if (
      curNode!.name === nodeBFSInterface.name &&
      nodeBFSInterface.attributes?.type === 'landerParent'
    ) {
      try {
        curNode!.children!.push({
          name: (nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName)?nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName : '',
          attributes: {
            type: nodeBFSInterface.attributes.type,
            url: nodeBFSInterface.attributes.url
              ? nodeBFSInterface.attributes.url
              : '',
            weight: nodeBFSInterface.attributes.weight
              ? nodeBFSInterface.attributes.weight
              : '',
          },
          children: [],
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      return { ...nodeBFSInterface.tree };
    }

    const len = curNode!.children!.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      queue.unshift(curNode!.children![i]);
    }
  }
}

export default nodeBFS;
```

I have tried the below as well but still get the same error. I checked whether value is not null and if null set it to empty string.

```
name: (nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName)?nodeBFSInterface.newNodeName: ''
```

Please advise on this.

Comment: Isn't the line throwing the error this one: `curNode!.name === nodeBFSInterface.name`? If so, you have to check if `nodeBFSInterface` is defined before accessing `nodeBFSInterface.name`.